# How to show JSON as formatted view in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, date, viewer

I need to view JSON in my html page as formatted view. JSON come from database. I need to show it nut in Formatted view.

Just like

```
 {
"crews": [{
    "items": [
    {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Blue",
        "position"  :   "1",
        "name"      :   "Patrick Close",
        "college"   :   "Pembroke",
        "weight"    :   "14st 2lbs"
    }, {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Blue",
        "position"  :   "2",
        "name"      :   "Geordie Macleod",
        "college"   :   "Christ Church",
        "weight"    :   "13st 10lbs"
    }]
}] 
}
```

Anyone have any idea or suggestion ? or any resource that may help.

Edited: I want to create a JSON parser. User input different json and can view in formatted view.

Comment: JSON beautify + `<pre>` tags?

Comment: `export function jsonToHtml(json)
{
  return "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(json, null, 4) + "</pre>";
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try JSON.stringify(data), its a Javascript function. Hope it might help.

Refer: [Detail Explaination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

If you are using PHP then use json_encode

Refer: [json_encode manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: I am using angular js and server side in java.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest to play around JSON.stringify().

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct, if you're problem is solved.

Comment: Your answer is not a solution... your answer is just a suggession. 
If it work correctly, i will mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using *angular-js*, you can simply load your *JSON* feed from your controller then use the `ng-repeat` function to iterate over the items into your view page. Here down a sample where of how your *HTML* view can look like and you may need to style and build the blocks as per your needs:

```html
<span>items:</span>
<span>[</span>
<br/>  
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>{</span><br/>
    <span class="field">year : {{item.year}}</span><br/>
    <span class="field">boat : {{item.boat}}</span><br/>
    <span class="field">position : {{item.position}}</span><br/>
    <span>}</span>
</div>
```

You can find a working sample in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmarwen/pJ5BR/2733/).

Comment: You have used item.year, item.boat in html. but i need dynamic. 

JSON can be modified in DB. then it should be viewed in html .

Answer (score 0):

First: your remote JSON is invalid: it's missing an ending bracket for `crews`.

It should be like this:

```
{
"crews": [{
    "items": [
    {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Blue",
        "position"  :   "1",
        "name"      :   "Patrick Close",
        "college"   :   "Pembroke",
        "weight"    :   "14st 2lbs"
    }, {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Blue",
        "position"  :   "2",
        "name"      :   "Geordie Macleod",
        "college"   :   "Christ Church",
        "weight"    :   "13st 10lbs"
    }]
}] // Missing this bracket
}
```

You didn't mention if your JSON is remote or not. I'm assuming not, so I'll use a local JavaScript var with `eval` function in this sample code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var content = {
"crews": [{
    "items": [
    {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Blue",
        "position"  :   "1",
        "name"      :   "Patrick Close",
        "college"   :   "Pembroke",
        "weight"    :   "14st 2lbs"
    }, {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Blue",
        "position"  :   "2",
        "name"      :   "Geordie Macleod",
        "college"   :   "Christ Church",
        "weight"    :   "13st 10lbs"
    }]
}]
};

var json = eval(content);

for (c in json.crews) {
    var crew = json.crews[c];
    for (i in crew.items) {
        var item = crew.items[i];
        console.log(item.year);
        console.log(item.boat);
        console.log(item.position);
        console.log(item.name);
    }
}

</script>
```

I'm using `console.log` to output, so you'll be able to see data only if you open the browser console:

[image]

Comment: At first, i want to parse the json in any format. It came from database. 
Your code is fixed for a specific format. 

To be more specific, i want to create a json parser.

Comment: Of course, the content inside the `for` loop should be changed to match what you need. It's just a sample!

Comment: for (c in json.crews) {
    var crew = json.crews[c];
    for (i in crew.items) {
        var item = crew.items[i];
        console.log(item.year);
        console.log(item.boat);
        console.log(item.position);
        console.log(item.name);
    }
}

this section work for all JSON ?